# Error installing R packages on Linux gcc -std=gnu99

Tags: r, linux

On a fresh install of Linux Mint 19.1. Previously had a recent version of Ubuntu on this system which ran R fine, only change is Mint is on a new SSD formatted ext4.

I try to install R packages such as:

```
install.packages("sys")
```

Returns the following compilation call:

gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-AitvI6/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c exec.c -o exec.o

and this error:

In file included from exec.c:1:0:
/usr/share/R/include/Rinternals.h:39:11: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
 # include 
           ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

My suspicion is that there's some issue with the way the hard disk is configured, as other applications also have errors installing, and must be installed on another hard disk.

Comment: What you showed (`gcc -std=gnu99 ... -c exec.c -o exec.o`) is not an error. It is a compile command. You should edit the question and provide the error from the command.

Comment: @jww Updated with error